# Ruby2d not working in WSL2 on Ubuntu 18.04 - Getting error "No available video device"

Tags: ruby, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2, ruby2d

I'm using WSL2 on Ubuntu 18.04 to run Ruby code in Windows 10.
For example, running **Ruby on Rails** is easily done with no special setup required.

In case of Ruby2D:
The installation went fine but, I get an error when running any Ruby2D file, even the most basic one:

```
require 'ruby2d'
show
```

I get this error in Console:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Error: (SDL_Init) No available video device
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Error: (SDL_CreateWindow) No available video device
Error: (GL2 / SDL_GL_CreateContext) Video subsystem has not been initialized
Error: An OpenGL context could not be created
```

How do I "add" (or config) a "video device" to my Ubuntu on the WSL2?

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed, WSL under Windows 10 doesn't have any GUI/X/windowing capabilities built in.  There are a few possibilities:

- If you have the ability to upgrade to Windows 11, it supports [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) (built-in) for running Linux GUI apps directly on Windows.  I did just install Ruby, ruby2d (and its dependencies) and was able to successfully execute your example.  I assume it is just supposed to show a blank GUI window ...

If you can't upgrade to Windows 11, there are still several possible alternatives for running Linux GUI apps.  I have not had a chance to test ruby2d in this type of environment, but I believe it should work.  If you run into issues, I can at least get the first option up and running to try it out and see if we can work through it:

- First, my preference is to install `xrdp` and a simple window manager like `xfce`.  See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986) for details and instructions.  You don't need the full Gnome environment (which requires Systemd) - A simple installation of Xfce should do.
- However, the most popular method is to install a third-party X server on Windows 10 and set up the `DISPLAY` variable manually.  If you'd like to go this route, see [this question and its answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1303964/1165986) for details.